# conversion of integers into binary in c++

Tags: c++, memory, types, binary, integer

As we know, each value is stored in binary form inside memory. So, in C++, will these two values have different binary numbers when stored inside memory ?

```
unsigned int a = 90;
signed int b = 90;
```

Comment: 90 is in range of both types, so they will have identical binary layouts in memory. Try using a value that is in range of one type but not the other, and see what happens.

Comment: I don't think standard mandates memory representation (we might have LeftToRight for signed and RightToLeft for unsigned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, in C++, will these two values have different binary numbers when stored inside memory ?

The C++ language doesn't specify whether they do. Ultimately, the binary representation is dictated by the hardware, so the answer technically depends on that.

That said, I haven't encountered hardware and C++ implementation where identically valued signed and unsigned variants of an integer didn't have identical binary representation. As such, I would find it surprising if the binary representations were different.

---

Sidenote: Since "byte" is the smallest addressable unit of memory in C++, there isn't a way in the language to observe a directional order of individual bits in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the value 63. In binary it is `111111` and in hex it is `3f`.

Because `char` is special in C++, and any object can be viewed as a sequence of bytes, you can directly look at the binary representation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 63;
    signed int b = 63;

    std::cout << std::hex;

    char* a_bin = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a);
    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(unsigned int); ++i) 
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<unsigned>(*(a_bin+i)) << " ";

    std::cout << "\n";

    char* b_bin = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b);
    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(signed int); ++i) 
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<unsigned>(*(b_bin+i)) << " ";   
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no `std::bin` io-manipulator, so I used `std::hex` (it is sticky). The `reinterpret_cast` is ok, because of the aforementioned special rules for `char`. Because `std::cout <<` has special overload to print characters, but we want to see numerical values, another cast is needed. The output of the above is:

```
003f 0000 0000 0000 
003f 0000 0000 0000
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aKocbjY1h)

As already mentioned in a comment, the byte order is implementation defined. Moreover, I have to admit that I am not aware about the very details of what the standard has to say about this. Be careful with assumptions about byte representation, especially when transfering objects between two programs or over a wire. You would typically use some form of de-/serialization, such that you are in control of the byte representations to be transfered.

TL;DR: Typically yes, in general you need to carefully consider what the C++ standard mandates, and I am not aware of signed and unsigned being guaranteed to have same byte representations.

Comment: Unfortunately (as often in C++), showing one case (on one platform) might just give hint on mandated behavior (or invalidate some wrong assumptions).

Comment: @Jarod42 indeed, I tried to clarify that. I wasn't sure what OP was expecting as answer, and I thought showing a way to look at one case could help.